# Solving for shape1 and shape2 in qbeta() given its quantiles in R

Tags: r, function, optimization, distribution, bayesian

**Background:**

`qbeta(p, shape1, shape2)` is an built-in base R function. In this function, `shape1` and `shape2` are always > 0 (for my purposes always > 1). Also, `p` is probability thus 0 <= p <= 1.

**Question:**

Suppose I know `qbeta(p = c(.025, .975), shape1 = x, shape2 = y ) = c(.3, .8 )`, THEN, is there a way I can find out what **x** and **y** could reasonably be (i.e., within some margin of error)?

**Note:** There are, I believe, some relevant comments and codes provided in **[HERE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112614/determining-beta-distribution-parameters-alpha-and-beta-from-two-arbitrary)**. So, in case one of the colleagues can makes sense or use of those codes and comments and apply them here, I'll  deeply appreciate it.

Finally, my ultimate goal is to **wrap a function** out of this **x** & **y** finding process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a brute force method. I'm hoping someone else can come up with a smarter way to do this.

```
d = expand.grid(shape1 = 1:100/10, shape2 = 1:100/10)

for (i in 1:NROW(d)){
    x = round(qbeta(p = c(0.025, 0.975), shape1 = d[i,1], shape2 = d[i,2]),2)
    if(x[1] > 0.28 & x[1] < 0.32 & x[2] > 0.78 & x[2] < 0.82){
        print(d[i,])
        break
    }
}

#     shape1 shape2
#5368    6.8    5.4

qbeta(p = c(.025, .975), shape1 = 6.8, shape2 = 5.4)
#[1] 0.2860268 0.8109389
```

I am providing [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)'s solution from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112671) below

```
################################
#REQUIRED FUNCTIONS
# Logistic transformation of the Beta CDF.
f.beta <- function(alpha, beta, x, lower=0, upper=1) {
    p <- pbeta((x-lower)/(upper-lower), alpha, beta)
    log(p/(1-p))
}

# Sums of squares.
delta <- function(fit, actual){
    sum((fit-actual)^2)
}

# The objective function handles the transformed parameters `theta` and
# uses `f.beta` and `delta` to fit the values and measure their discrepancies.
objective <- function(theta, x, prob, ...) {
    ab <- exp(theta) # Parameters are the *logs* of alpha and beta
    fit <- f.beta(ab[1], ab[2], x, ...)
    return (delta(fit, prob))
}
################################

#INPUT
x <- c(.3, .8)
x.p <- (function(p) log(p/(1-p)))(c(0.025, 0.975))

#SOLVE
start <- log(c(1e1, 1e1))
sol <- nlm(objective, start, x=x, prob=x.p, lower=0, upper=1,
                        typsize=c(1,1), fscale=1e-12, gradtol=1e-12)
parms <- exp(sol$estimate)

#ANSWER
parms
#[1] 7.597429 6.016240

#TEST
qbeta(p = c(.025, .975), parms[1], parms[2])
#[1] 0.3 0.8
```